# How run IF condition on serverversion 5.5

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I run an IF condition on av MySQL serverversion 5.5?

```
a.column1 = IF(b.column2 = 'STRING', '2012-01-01', a.column1)
```

On my XAMPP localhost server the above code works perfectly (serverversion 10), but my host provider runs serverversion 5.5 and there the above code gets error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Does any one know a workaround?

EDIT:
Here's the rest of the query:

```
UPDATE table1 a INNER JOIN table2 b ON (a.id = b.other_id) SET
b.column1='something',
a.column1 = IF(b.column2 = 'STRING', '2012-01-01', a.column1)
WHERE a.id = '41' AND b.other_id = '3150'
```

And as I said before, this query works perfect on XAMPP (serverversion 10) but I get error #1064 on my webbhost (serverversion 5.5).

EDIT 2:
Been trying to repelece the IF statement with CASE but I cant get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
UPDATE table1 a INNER JOIN table2 b ON (a.id = b.other_id) SET
b.column1='something'
CASE
  WHEN b.column2 = 'STRING' THEN a.column2 = '2012-01-01'
  ELSE NULL
END
WHERE a.id='3' AND b.other_id = '3'
```

Been also trying this, but it doesn't work either, getting error #1064:

```
UPDATE table1 a INNER JOIN table2 b ON (a.id = b.other_id)  
SET a.column2 = CASE
  WHEN b.column2 = 'STRING' THEN '2012-01-01',
  ELSE a.column2
END
b.column1='something'
WHERE a.id='3' AND b.other_id = '3'
```

Comment: Looks correct - could you post the whole SQL query?

Comment: For a workaround, a case construct would do the trick.

Comment: No, doesn't work. The query executes but no value changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CASE construct was the answer. Sadly I don't have an answer to set as correct.

This is the code that worked:

```
$query ="UPDATE table1 a 
INNER JOIN table2 b 
ON (a.id = b.other_id) SET
b.column1='STRING',
a.column1 = CASE WHEN b.column2 = 'STRING' THEN 'something' ELSE column1 END
WHERE a.id = 3 AND b.other_id = 3
```